# I can't find the remote desktop option in my pc

Tags: windows

Here is a screenshot of what I expect to get in the remote tab of my PC:

[image: screenshot]

However, I can't find the 'Allow remote connections to this computer' checkbox on my machine. Can anyone help?

I am using Windows Home version: 1803

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Home does not have the functionality to be used as a Remote Desktop server natively.

However, there are ways around this limitation as described in [this blog](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/how-to-rdpwrapper-win10-home).
An alternative suggested there is the [RDP Wrapper Library by Stas'M](https://github.com/stascorp/rdpwrap/). According to its description:

> The goal of this project is to enable Remote Desktop Host support and
>   concurrent RDP sessions on reduced functionality systems for home
>   usage.

Describing how to install and setup this wrapper is out of the scope of this question, but if you have specific issue, feel free to post a new question.